# Using child themes depending on browser width

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

Is it possible to use a different child theme depending on the browser width?

I realize there are the CSS media queries to change stylesheets, but I'm wondering if it's possible for a phone with like 420px width load the page, and the header.php sees this and points it to a different header file.

If this isn't possible, or if it is quite difficult, I would then need to find a way to get it to point to a specific WordPress page (as it's in WordPress) depending on that width.

In short, with the way I set stuff up, I'm just trying to avoid the CSS media queries.

I apologize in advance if this is something simple or overly complicated. I'm a bit green in programming. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS media queries are just a way of altering CSS depending on the browser width (which im sure you know), in your case I would use CSS media queries, but if your thinking i dont know what rules to set etc then maybe this reference will help

```
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/
```

CSS media queries are not complicated, they are just stylesheets for different screen widths

Comment: Thanks for the link! I may end up backtracking my work and fitting it for media queries, but I'm still curious if there's a way in which I described in my question with jQuery or something.

Comment: The way you are thinking of doing things is just adding work and effort, media queries are clean, quick and simple. if you need any help just give us a shout